# Logstash security

Tags: security, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am wondering if it is possible to implement something like mutual handshake authorization between logstash and logstash-forwarder?

At the moment, I know that logstash provides ***ssl certificates***
for security, but I am not sure if this is the best way to protect my logs flow.

The certificates are not safe enough in my case. If they will get stolen then you are in danger.. Looking for something else that may help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like I was looking for mutual authentication between LSF (or FileBeat) and Logstash.

Here is what I found - there is an open [issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-beats/issues/8), while it is opened, the problem is not solved.

[Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-setup-filebeat-with-basic-auth-for-logstash-output/36937/12) is some discussion on this topic:

> filebeat has same support as logstash-forwarder used to have, plus some more fine-grained TLS configs (e.g. choose TLS version or configure ciphers). Connection can encrypted via TLS + server certificated is validated. Filebeat itself supports TLS client-auth, BUT logstash must enforce (ask for certificate) client authentication, which is not implemented yet (see github issue).

Answer (score 2):

The Logstash forwarder project [has been deprecated](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder#this-project-is-replaced-by-filebeat) in favor of the Filebeat project.

Generally, you should now prefer using Filebeat over Logstash forwarder. Moreover, Filebeat allows you to [set up TLS client authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration-details.html#configuration-output-tls), which is what you're after.

Comment: Cool! Thank you Val! But I still can not understand - what is the main difference between filebeat and logstash-forwarder?

Comment: Filebeat is simply the new Logstash forwarder. It is part of the [Elastic Beats](https://www.elastic.co/about/press/elastic-acquires-packetbeat) framework, a new generation of data forwarders provided by Elastic. You can read more about Filebeat at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to hepl!