# Explicitlly Set logstash-forwarder log file location

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I am wondering how you can explicitly set the logstash-forwarder log file location. For some reason I don't see any options for this. For my Linux VM's, it is not a (big) problem as they get stored in /var/log/logstash-forwarder/ however in Windows, I cannot seem to find them anywhere.

I looked around with the options when running logstash-forwarder -help, but it doesn't seem to provide any options. Google doesn't help either.

I have tried -syslog=true / -log-t-syslog=true which doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember setting up logstash-forwarder as windows service with [nssm-2.24](https://nssm.cc/) some time ago. The nssm-2.24 has an I/O tab where you can specify the stdout and stderr redirection.

As for the logstash-forwarder itself it uses [Go Package log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#example_Logger) (see [syslog_windows.go](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder/blob/master/syslog_windows.go) source file) and I don't know where those logs are send by default.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35147396/1823545) suggests upgrading to [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html) as [logstash-forwarder is deprecated](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder#this-project-is-replaced-by-filebeat). However the [syslog_other.go](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/libbeat/logp/syslog_other.go) file from this project makes me wonder if this is good idea in your case.

Comment: Thank you.. After posting this I did realize that logstash-forwarder just used stdout and stderr redirection (which I saw in the init scripts on the Linux servers). I ended up going the direction of Filebeat as I was not getting much support for the old logstash-forwarder shipper even on forums / IRC.